# Can "It's not it" be expressed in any language in less than 3 words

Tags: list-of-languages, translation

Let's look at the sentence "It's not it"

In Hebrew it's "זה לא זה" (lit. it no it)

In French C'est n'est pas ca

In all the languages I'm familiar with, in order to say "It's not it", one needs at leat three words - one specifying the object we're talking about, another word in order to specify the object we compare with, and at least one word to make the negative predicate happen. Obviously different languages may decorate these three words with more words, because the grammatical construct requires it  (just like in French)

My question is : is there a language where we can say "it's not it" with **less** than three words?

Comment: Do you require both "it"s to be explicit? Because there are many pro-drop languages where it's totally natural to drop pronouns if it's clear from context, so you can end up with "is not it" or even "is not", which can be expressed in two/one word(s) in Korean, for example.

Comment: @jick heck, even in English, say I ask someone to send me a particular photo and they send the wrong one: "Not it!"

Comment: You must specify the context.  In Russian in some contexts we could say Не это, Этот нет and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As jick mentioned, there are languages where it's natural to drop the `it`

For instance, in Turkish, it's even more natural to drop it:

- Bu o değil. (This is not that.)
- Değil. (It isn't/It isn't it.)

Because the word `değil` already specifies that the pronoun is `it`. `değilim` is `I'm not`, `değilsin` is `you're not/you aren't` and `değil` is `it isn't/it's not`.

I had to change `it` to `this, that` in order to give natural feel. You can think of it like `O değil`. This is an issue with Turkish, but since you ask that is it possible to use `subject + negation + object` less than three words, I need to come up with an another sentence.

- Bu o at mı? (Is this the horse (that you mentioned)?)
- Değil (It's not it)
- Bu bir at mı? (Is this a horse?)
- Değil (It's not)

That `değil` word can mean `it isn't, it isn't it` regarding the question. Also, it can't be used in meaning of simply `no`.

- Bu o at mı? (Is this the horse (that you mentioned)?)
- Hayır (No.) - This one is **correct.**
- Bu at koşuyor mu? (Is this horse running?)
- Değil (It isn't.) - This one is **incorrect.**, right negative answer would be `hayır`.

It's meaningless to use all the pronouns in Turkish. `O o değil.` I have never heard that.